# Как открыть окно customtkinter в полноэкранном режиме

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Light")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x500")
app.title("Win locker")
# app.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, justify=tkinter.LEFT, text="hello")
label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app.mainloop()
```

метод app.attributes("-fullscreen", True) не работает

Comment: У меня также ваша проблема не воспроизводиться. Вы пользуетесь Pycharm, может изменили какие-то настройки?

Comment: И эта строка не нужна `app.geometry("400x500")`